# Does OnStopEditing always happen after OnSave

Tags: arcobjects, c#, events

During debugging, I discovered that the `OnSaveEdits` event is always followed by `OnStopEditing` and then `OnStartEditing`. Is this always the case?

I don't see the logic in this. I could understand if `OnSave` was fired after `OnStopEditing` (if the user choses to save), but not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, this has always the case for as long as I can remember. When you think about it it is logical: save edits stops and starts the editor thus the events are fired.